# Using the fuser command to kill processes using a mount point is taking a long time

Tags: mount, kill, fuser

I am trying to kill processes with open file handles on a mount point before performing unmount. We observed for a few mount points, the below `fuser` command is taking a long time. It took more than 3 minutes and still it didn't finish.

We haven't opened the mount point in any of our sessions, so the mount point is not busy.

```
fuser -vcMk mount-point-path
```

Please provide a resolution or troubleshooting steps for this issue.